# Compile the same C code for user space as well as kernel space

Tags: c, makefile, kernel

lets say i have a .h and .c file, originally written for kernel space.

```
#ifndef __TREE_H__
#define __TREE_H__

 /* #includes for kernel headers*/

struct tree_node_t{
  int data;
  struct tree_node_t *left;
  struct tree_node_t *right;
};

struct tree{
 int data;
 struct tree_node_t *root;
};

void insert_node(struct tree *tree, int data);
#endif
```

Lets say, the corresponding .c file contains the definition of void insert_node fn, which create a tree_node using `kmalloc()` and insert it into a tree. I am able to compile the code using Makefile to compile the kernel modules as the .h/.c file are part of kernel module.

Now, i want to use the same data structure and its fns in userspace as well. I need to compile it using new user space specific makefile which takes care to replace the kernel specific calls like `kmalloc` and `kfree` with `malloc` and `free` instead ? How can i use various combination of #ifdef #else #endif so that the files are compilable in user space and kernel space by using respective make files.

pls Nte : `kmalloc/kfree` are just simple examples to explain. Files contain other kernel specific APIs which needs to be excluded/replaced at the time compilation of file in user space.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. refactor the code and split it into different modules. If it is deeply woven with kernel functions, it is a bad idea to use it for user-space, too.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `__KERNEL__` macro for differentiate target of compilation: kernel code (macro is defined) or application (macro is not defined).

Exactly this macro is used in Linux kernel for *uapi* headers and some other files. See, e.g., [include/uapi/linux/ethtool.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/ethtool.h#L20).